# WebRTC video chat not working on iOS Safari or iOS Chrome - Is it possible?

Tags: ios, webrtc, videochat, simplewebrtc, live-video

I am not technical but have my engineer working on putting together a web-based video chat application with the goal of using it on the iOS web browser(s). The service appears to be functioning correctly on a desktop browser. However, we cannot get it to work on iOS browsers.

on Safari (using iPhone 11 - iOS 13) the video freezes immediately and shows still frame. On Chrome there is never a connection made, nor does Chrome prompt to access camera/mic.

I've read conflicting work that says WebRTC is supported in iOS Safari/Chrome and other work that says it is not.

Would appreciate anyone's help here! Is it possible to create a URL-based video conferencing platform that can correctly function on iPhone?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding 'muted', 'autoplay', 'playsinline' attributes to the Video Element as shown below.

```
<video muted autoplay playsinline></video>
```

If you can play it back, it's ok.
From the perspective of the user experience, the browser can autoplay audio or video with audio only on some sites such as Youtube and sites that the user has allowed. It cannot be done on other sites.
To play on sites that can't autoplay, modify it to play with user gestures such as clicks.

```
video.onclick = _ => video.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that works from Raspberry Pi to iPhone iOS 13.4
Haven't been able to make it work from Chrome on windows to iPhone
https://apprtc.tc

source code:
https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc

GetUserMedia is not supported in Chrome for iPhone
It is supported in Safari for iPhone
It is supported in Chrome for Windows